# extension not loading on url change

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

My content.js is not running when I click on a link. The url changes (content.js runs when hitting F5). The content that gets updated is inside of a frame.

How do I trigger my content.js to run without press F5?

```
{
"name":"My name",
"description":"My description!",
"version":"1",
"manifest_version":2,
"browser_action": {
"default_icon": "icon.png"
},
"content_scripts": [
{
    "matches": ["http://www.somePage.com/article*"],
    "js": ["content.js"]
}]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try to set the "all_frames" to true in order that when a frame in a page is updated the content script will be injected again like in the following:

```html
"content_scripts": [
{
  "matches": [ "http://www.somePage.com/article*" ],
  "all_frames": true,
  "js": [ "content.js" ]
}
```